# Separate css file for JavaFX project

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-11

How can I apply a certain style for all lines objects in a separate css file for a javaFX project? This is the java code :

```
package com.example.demo;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 800);
        stage.setTitle("Simulink viewer");
        Label l1 = new Label("hdkhsd");
        l1.setLayoutX(100);
        l1.setLayoutY(100);
        Label l2 = new Label("helle");
        l2.setLayoutX(400);
        l2.setLayoutY(400);
        root.getChildren().addAll(l1,l2);
        Line l = new Line(10,10,90,90);
        root.getChildren().add(l);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

And this is the css file:

```
.root{
-fx-background-color : #ADD8E6;
}

.label {
-fx-border-color: red;
}

.line {
-fx-stroke = green;

}
```

The style works for both root and label, but it doesn't work for line. What is the problem?

I'm having this warning:

> May 13, 2023 4:31:05 PM javafx.css.CssParser declaration
> WARNING: CSS Error parsing file:/E:/College/Now/Advanced/Projects/normal%20java%20projects/demo/target/classes/com/example/demo/style.css: Expected COLON at [10,11]

I actually read that style class for line is empty by default. What does that mean? Does it mean I can't style line in a separate css file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, note you have a syntax error in your CSS file:

```
-fx-stroke = green;
```

should be

```
-fx-stroke: green;
```

Additionally, note from the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#line) that the style class of `Line` is empty by default. (Only `Control` and its subclasses, along with `ImageView`, `WebView`, and `MediaView` have default style classes.) Consequently, the selector will not select the line. You can either add the style class to the line explicitly:

```
    Line l = new Line(10,10,90,90);
    l.getStyleClass().add("line");
```

or us a Type Selector. From the documentation:

> Node's getTypeSelector method returns a String which is analogous to a CSS Type Selector. By default, this method returns the simple name of the class.

So the following will work without adding the style class in the Java code:

```
Line {
-fx-stroke: green;

}
```